# Populate Android Spinner with mySQL data

Tags: php, android, json

I have a spinner that I would like to populate with data from a database on my localhost. I have the following .php file which accesses the data, I was hoping this would pass the data back to Android, but I'm not sure how to code the .java file in order for it to work.

```
<?php
    $host='localhost';
    $uname='root';
    $pwd='';
    $db='footballtickets';
    $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");
    $results=mysql_query("select * from tickettypes",$con);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results))
    {
        $cls[]=$row;
    }
    print(json_encode($cls));
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

How do I populate a spinner in Eclipse? Currently using API2.2, not sure if I would need to change this in order for it to work.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I tried using the answer from this question to assist me, no luck though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164744/populate-two-spinners-from-mysql-database-that-are-dependant-to-each-other